# Calling a function of a module dynamically

Tags: python-2.7

I have a function get_more() in class DoThisForThat which when directly used can be called like this:

```
new = DoThisForThat(opt1=something, opt2=blah).add_more(opt3=more1, opt4=more2).add_more(opt3=more10, opt4=more11)
```

I am building a wrapper that consumes .json files and dynamically generates the above call. I am really new to python and unsure about how to achieve this. I looked at some of the option and looks like getattr is my best bet? Any help would be much appreciated :)

EDIT:

I have tried setting that up not so "dynamically" where the json configs are restricted to using 2 metrics at a time. But say if a user had more metrics, where ".add_more()" needs to be called for the number of metrics provided, I am not sure how to go about it. If you can point me in the right direction I can try it out. At this point I am not even sure how would I call ".add_more(opt3=...,opt4=...)" dynamically. Current config:

```
{"add_more":[ {"metric":"sum(impressions)", "days":"13"},
              {"metric":"count(rollups)", "days":"7"},
              {"metric":"avg(clicks)", "days":"2"} 
            ]}
```

Currently, with the way I have it it up, the users are forced to provide two configs at a time. So I basically have something like this:

```
setup_call = DoThisForThat(opt1="tbl_name",
                           opt2="schema"
                          ).add_more(
                           opt3="sum(impressions)",
                           opt4="13"
                          ).add_more(
                           opt3="sum(impressions)",
                           opt4="7"
                          )
```

The third metric that was provided in the json config above was ignored since the setup of calling "add_more()" is not dynamic

Comment: I have tried setting that up not so "dynamically" where the json configs are restricted to using 2 metrics at a time. But say if a user had more metrics, where ".add_more()" needs to be called for the number of metrics provided, I am not sure how to go about it. If you can point me in the right direction I can try it out. At this point I am not even sure how would I call ".add_more(opt3=...,opt4=...)" dynamically.  current config:
    {"add_more":[
    {"metric":"sum(impressions)", "days":"13"},
    {"metric":"count(rollups)", "days":"7"},
    {"metric":"avg(clicks)", "days":"2"}
]}

Comment: Currently, with the way I have it it up, the users are forced to provide two configs at a time. So I basically have something like this: 

setup_call = DoThisForThat(opt1="tbl_name", opt2="schema").add_more(opt3="sum(impressions)", opt4="13").add_more(opt3="sum(impressions)", opt4="7")

The third metric that was provided in the json config above was ignored since the setup of calling "add_more()" is not dynamic.

Comment: Please Add that to your question, with the code properly formatted.

Comment: how about variable arguments? *kwargs or **args? is that the kind of thing you are after?